# camel:xpath. Selecting multiple values from a single node

Tags: xpath, apache-camel, spring-dsl

I want to select a multiple values from an XML node.

ex:

```
<Root>
  <SubRoot>
      <Parent>Hiddic</Parent>
      <Mother>Vim</Mother>
   </SubRoot>
   <SubRoot>
      <Parent>Richie</Parent>
      <Mother>Vile</Mother>
   </SubRoot>
   <SubRoot>
      <Parent>Stroog</Parent>
      <Mother>Murukku</Mother>
   </SubRoot>
</Root>
```

From this example i want to extract the SubRoot nodes where  is equals to **Vim** and **Vile**. I am using camel Xpath expression for this. And i am giving the inputs using a properties file.

This is the code i am using:

```
    <setHeader headerName="newBody">
                <xpath>//SubRoot[contains(Mother,"${properties:AlgoPosition.product.type.value}")]</xpath>
    </setHeader>
```

The value in the property file is,

```
AlgoPosition,poduct.type.value = Vim,Vile;
```

If i give a single value in the property it retrieves me the correct node but when i give multiple values its failing. Please Help me in selecting multiple values.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you post the XML file that is used as input?

Comment: The XPath expression would be `//SubRoot[contains(Mother,"Vim") or contains(Mother,"Vile")]`. Can't help you with Camel XPath though.

Comment: Yeah you can use some xpath expression to select multiples using OR as paul says above. Usually it can be a little hard to get the xpath expression to work as expected, but there is some tools that can do live xpath editing so you can use that to write a working xpath expression to copy into the source code afterwards.